# Error con SharedPreferences desde un ViewHolder

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-recyclerview

Estoy intentando guardar unos datos desde un `ViewHolder`, a través de un evento, de momento no se me ocurre nada mejor para poder luego trabajar con el dato, no podemos usar bases de datos.

Así que estoy intentando actualizar el `SharedPreference` en el `ViewHolder`:

```
public class AdapterJuice extends RecyclerView.Adapter<AdapterJuice.ViewHolderData> {

    public ArrayList<Juice> listData;
    public Context context;

    public AdapterJuice(ArrayList<Juice> listData) {
        this.listData = listData;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public AdapterJuice.ViewHolderData onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.activity_juice_list, null, false);
        return new ViewHolderData(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull AdapterJuice.ViewHolderData holder, int position) {
        holder.edtName.setText(listData.get(position).getName());
        holder.edtCuantity.setText(listData.get(position).getCuantity());
        holder.edtPrice.setText(listData.get(position).getPrice());
        holder.imgPhoto.setImageResource(listData.get(position).getPhoto());
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return listData.size();
    }

    public class ViewHolderData extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        private TextView edtName;
        private TextView edtCuantity;
        private TextView edtPrice;
        private ImageView imgPhoto;

        public ViewHolderData(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            edtName = itemView.findViewById(R.id.idProductName);
            edtCuantity = itemView.findViewById(R.id.idValuesOrder);
            edtPrice = itemView.findViewById(R.id.idPrice);
            imgPhoto = itemView.findViewById(R.id.idImage);

            itemView.findViewById(R.id.idIncrement).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    int cuantity;
                    cuantity = Integer.parseInt(edtCuantity.getText().toString());
                    cuantity++;
                    edtCuantity.setText(String.valueOf(cuantity));

                    SharedPreferences preferences = context.getSharedPreferences("juice", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
                    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = preferences.edit();
                    editor.putString(edtName.getText().toString(), String.valueOf(cuantity));
                    editor.apply();
                }
            });
        }
    }
}
```

La cuestión es que me da error en esta línea:

```
SharedPreferences preferences = context.getSharedPreferences("juice", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
```

Y el error:

> java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.content.SharedPreferences android.content.Context.getSharedPreferences(java.lang.String, int)' on a null object reference

Comment: `context` es null. Comprueba que estes asignando el valor a la variable.

Comment: @Einer he añadido la clase completa, Context lo inicializo en la clase AdapterJuice, pero no lo asigno, ¿cómo tendría que hacerlo?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tienes que inicializar el contexto pasando por como parametro por el constructor asi:

```
  public AdapterJuice(ArrayList<Juice> listData, Context context) {
        this.listData = listData;
        this.context = context;
    }
```

Entonces cuando inicializes el adapter desde tu Activity le pasas el context:

```
AdapterJuice adapter = new AdapterJuice(data, this);
```

Comment: Muchísimas gracias Einer por tu ayuda.